# Sieve filter remove detail part from subaddress

Tags: email, dovecot, sieve

I currently have a sieve filter that looks like the following:

```
require ["variables", "envelope", "fileinto", "vnd.dovecot.filter", "subaddress"];
if envelope :matches "to" "*" {
        set :lower "my_recipient" "${1}";
        filter ".." "${my_recipient}";
        fileinto "INBOX";
}
```

This works great. However my filter current is unable to correctly handle sub-addresses such as: ken+sieve@example.org

So I would like to set the `my_recipient` variable to be ken@example.org in order to the filter to work correctly, even when the envelope was set to ken+sieve@example.org

I have read through the [subaddress documentation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5233), and I can see how to get i.e the `user` part or the `domain` part, but not how to get the full address including domain without the `detail` part. How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works

```
if envelope :user :matches "to" "*" {
    set :lower "user" "${1}";
    if envelope :domain :matches "to" "*" {
        set :lower "domain" "${1}";
        set "my_recipient" "${user}@${domain}";
            filter ".." "${my_recipient}";
            fileinto "INBOX";
    }
}
```